# SSH asking for port 22 while using passwordless login

Tags: ssh

Here is the case

Im using port different port for ssh on all linux servers . And i generated ssh keys and when i use

`ssh oracle@proddb -pxxxx`x

server logins with no problem

But if i use "ssh proddb" connection is refused

```
ssh: connect to host proddb port 22: Connection refused
```

## Verbosity

## ssh -v prodb

```
> OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008 debug1: Reading
> configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config debug1: Applying options for *
> debug1: Connecting to proddb [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22. debug1:
> connect to address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused ssh:
> connect to host proddb port 22: Connection refused
```

Comment: distant host is not listening on port 22, and by the way your public key are deployed on root account, you should user `root@` too.

Comment: sorry it is oracle user, on some servers "ssh proddb" command works and on some it is not

Comment: then your public keys are to be deployed on remote oracle account. (e.g. in `~oracle/.ssh/authorized_keys` )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SSH is using port 22 as default port.
You could create a config file in your .ssh folder and configure your port etc.:

### content of $HOME/.ssh/config

```
Host proddb
    HostName proddb
    Port xxxx
    User root
```

Comment: There is already a file in "oracle's/.ssh/config"  and it is using port 15666 which is correct i added "User oracle" and then restarted service. But still giving connection refused

Comment: check the syntax of your config file

start ssh with "-v"   to debug
you should see line like this 

debug1: Reading configuration data /home/oracle/.ssh/config

Comment: Your verbosity list shows, ssh is reading config from wrong file 

--- debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config


--- It must read it from your "/home/oracle/.ssh/config"

Comment: This solution worked, further more i edited /etc/ssh/ssh_config and altered the port and it also worked. Thanks @vafa